# How to make Swift protocol conformed by a specific kind of Class?

Tags: ios, swift, class, protocols

I wrote a protocol in Swift:

```
protocol FooDelegate{
    titleImage:UIImage? {get}
}
```

I want to make sure that the class that conforms to it must be a UITableViewController type.

In other words:

```
// ViewController conform FooDelegate is OK,Because ViewController 
// is inherit from UITableViewController!
class ViewController:UITableViewController,FooDelegate /* compile ok */{

}

// OtherVC is failed to conform FooDelegate,Because it is not inherit
// from UITableViewController.
class OtherVC:UIViewController,FooDelegate /* will compile error */{

}
```

How to do that?

I changed FooDelegate's definition to this:

```
protocol FooDelegate where Self:UITableViewController {
    var titleImage:UIImage? {get}
}
```

But it does not seem to work.

*** FIX PART ***:
Use Self:UITableViewController is OK!!!

But when I write below is wrong when compiling :

```
class StubClass{
    var delegate:FooDelegate!

    func invoke(){
        let idxSet = ...
        delegate.tableView.reloadSections(idxSet, with: .none) //Error:Value of type 'FooDelegate' has no member 'tableView'
    }
}
```

Please look at the line that Error above. Isn't there any tableView property in delegate? delegate is conform to FooDelegate,and FooDelegate make Self:UITableViewController,and UITableViewController must have tableView property??!!

What's wrong here??? Thanks :)

Comment: What version of Swift are you using? The feature you're looking for was added recently (I believe in 4.1). Your `Self: UITableViewController` should work.

Comment: I using 4.1，But it's not work！something wrong？

Comment: OK,my mistake!!! use Self:UITableViewController is working!!!But there are other error where use it!See "Fix Part" above please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `tableView` property is not visible to the protocol declaration you just need to add the `tableView` property in the protocol. Something like this:

```
@objc protocol FooDelegate where Self: UITableViewController {
    var tableView: UITableView { get }
}

class SimpleTableView: UITableViewController, FooDelegate {

}

let delegate: FooDelegate? = SimpleTableView()

delegate?.tableView.reloadData()
```

Remeber to add `@objc` in protocol declaration.

Comment: Thanks!I know add tableView property in FooDelegate is working...,I just don't understand why it's can't smart infer to there have one tableView property in delegate ...

Comment: @hopy I think by using conditional conformance we can access the properties and methods inside the protocol or protocol extension but we cannot access them with the protocol reference to maintain the abstraction of the class.

Comment: @hopy So if we have to provide the access to some property or method we have to declare it in protocol.

Comment: Correct; the current level of type inference in the compiler allows it to enforce inheritance at the point of conformance (i.e. it can check that the class actually inherits), but it does not embed this information in the protocol. That's why it `protocol P where Self: C` rather than `protocol P: C`. The protocol is not (currently) a subtype of the class (and in fact may be indirection box).

Comment: I understand now,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
protocol FooDelegate: class where Self: UITableViewController {
    // code
}
```

And if you want certain extensions to be accessible by `UITableViewController`:

```
protocol FooDelegate {
    // code
}

extension FooDelegate where Self: UITableViewController {
    // code
}
```