# Is that a bug in Swift Compiler?

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I write a protocol (in Xcode playground),and want it be conform by specified class , eg: Root.

Because I used Swift 4.1 , So there are new syntax for this :

```
protocol Delegate where Self:Root{
    var titleImage:UIImage? {get}
}
```

(PS:If you want to know more about this , please follow the link : [How to make Swift protocol conformed by a specific kind of Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50092984/how-to-make-swift-protocol-conformed-by-a-specific-kind-of-class))

And I also write class Root and Foo :

```
class Root:Delegate{
    var titleImage:UIImage?

    func willDo(){
        let foo = Foo()
        foo.delegate = self
        foo.invoke()
    }
}

class Foo{
    var delegate:Delegate!

    func invoke(){
        if let image = delegate.titleImage{
            print("have a image [\(image)")
        }else{
            print("not have a image")
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I call :

```
let r = Root()
r.willDo()
```

Here are runtime error :

[image]

But when I changed Delegate code to this :

```
protocol Delegate{
    var titleImage:UIImage? {get}
}
```

That's all right!!! But it can't limited Delegate to be conform by class Root anymore!

Could anyone can tell me Why is it? Why when add " Self:Root " to Delegate will trigger a BAD_ACCESS Runtime error???

Is this a Bug in Swift or I misunderstand something???

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: AFAIK being able to use class constraints in protocol `where` clauses isn't something that's fully supported currently – that's tracked by [SR-6001](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6001). The specific runtime crash you're getting looks like [SR-6816](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6816).

Comment: @NaderBesada Is your Swift 4.1 in Version 9.3 (9E145) ??? Ary you mean  my Xcode Version is too old???

Comment: So it's seem be a Bug??? @Hamish

Comment: Restart Xcode or test in real project (not in playground) are all not working... But thank you anyway ;) @NaderBesada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `@objc` when declaring your protocol

```
@objc protocol Delegate where Self: Root{
    var titleImage: UIImage? {get}
}
```

This is a current [bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-7068) in swift so wrapping it in `@objc` should work